# Mutiple correct choice question based on inverse trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

This one is a multiple correct choice question.$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{arcsec}\DeclareMathOperator{\arccsc}{arccsc}\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}$

$f(x)=\frac{\arcsin x}{\arccos x}+\frac{\arccos x}{\arctan x}+\frac{\arctan x}{\arcsec x}+\frac{\arcsec x}{\arccsc x}+\frac{\arccsc x}{\arccot x}+\frac{\arccot x}{\arcsin x}$

Then which of the following statements holds good?

$(A)$minimum value of $f(x)$ is 6.

$(B)f(x)$ is a continuous function.

$(C)f(-1)=\frac{-107}{12}$

$(D)f(x)$ is a non-derivable at $x=-1.$

There seems no way to simplify the function. How should I attempt this question, if this complicated function is not simplified?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here Function $\sin^{-1}(x),\cos^{-1}(x)$ is defined when $-1\leq x\leq 1$

and Function $\csc^{-1}(x),\sec^{-1}(x)$ is defined when $x\leq -1\cup x\geq 1$

and Function $\tan^{-1}(x),\cot^{-1}(x)$ is defined when $-\infty <x<\infty$

So overall domain of function is $x=\pm 1$

Now Calculate value of Function $f(x)$ at $x=\pm 1$

Comment: ... and if a function is defined only on a closed interval $[a,b]$, it's not continuous (or differentiable) at $x=a$ or $x=b$.

Comment: Then function $\bf{R.H.S}$ cont. and diff. at $x=a$ and $\bf{L.H.S}$ Cont. at $x=b$.

Comment: @CarlHeckman,what can we say about its minimum value?

Comment: @CarlHeckman,but its domain is not in interval form,its domain is just two points.Can we still apply the rule suggested by you?

Comment: If the domain doesn't contain an interval, it's not differentiable anywhere. For instance, the function $n!$ is not differentiable, because $n!$ only exists when $x\in \{ 0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: The above concept is a very beautiful concept.I did not know it.@Carl Heckman